# For loop on dataframe to delete

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, for-loop

I am new to spark and azure. I have saved the result of a dataframe in a temp table using databricks.
I have a similar table (same structure) in postgres database.
Now, I want to delete the rows in postgres table which has the same column value as in temp table (WHERE temp_table.column2 = postgres_table.column2).
For this I want to iterate through the rows of that temp table using FOR loop and DELETE the matching rows from postgres table.

```
Example:    
For rows in temp table sample_table -> 
   WHEN sample_table.column_name = postgres_table.column_name
   THEN DELETE postgres_table.column_name;
```

Comment: It would be easier to write the spark dataframe into a temp table in postgresql then do batch delete using join.

Comment: True. But the problem is we are not allowed to create temp table in postgres. The deletion is supposed to occur on postgres and after deletion of common rows, the data in temp table has to be loaded into it.

Comment: `DELETE FROM a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM b WHERE b.y = a.x)` <<-- No loops!

Comment: There are many things on SO, use foreachPartition

Comment: Thanks, guys. But it will be really helpful if you could please share an answer using FOR loop with the syntax given above.